# How can we add this type of one onto another using html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey how can we add one onto another in HTML and css like given in the pic.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZHKR.jpg

Comment: can you tell little more about what your asking,

Comment: As @prasanna said, we would need code and more description of what you have already tried so we can help you with your problem. We can't really help you with only a picture. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to have some code of your own where we can see the problem and where you can get stuck. You can use negative `margin` to place a element at the top of the other to achieve the float effect.

Because you didn't provide any code of your own I produced a little example of how this works with HTML/CSS.

```css
. {
  position: relative;
  margin: -60px auto 0 auto; /* float + padding */
  background: white;
}

. {
  padding: 40px;
  background: orangered;
}

. {
  padding: 40px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

/* misc styling */
. {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
 }
```

```html
<section class="">
  <h1>Unhealthy food causes problems</h1>
</section>
<section class="">
  <div class="">I'm floating.</div>
  <h1>Try a salad next time!</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey I have done this but when I put this image gets expanding.

Comment: There are two options here, you can improve your question by adding the HTML/CSS you are talking about. Or I walk 1500 hours to India and have a look. You need to be _very_ clear about what your asking or else we can't help.